# How to change UILabel value from another tab on my XCODE

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, uiview

I have my app that have some tab's (tabbar).

In the first tab, there are UILabel's, and on the third tab, there is methods, linked to buttons.

I want to change the value of the UILabel's from the methods of the third button (launched trough those buttons)

Here is some code to illustrate all that :

FIRST PAGE (with UILabels)
    @implementation FirstViewController

```
// definition des accesseurs
@synthesize details;
@synthesize recapitulatif;

...
```

And the method that will change the UILabels (SECOND PAGE WIHT BUTTONS - with the actual functions, don't pay attention to those methods ;-) )

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    [connection release];

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [responseData release];
    //NSString *responseString2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s%@%s", "[", responseString, "]"]; // Pour ajouter les [] si y'en a pas autour de tout le contenu JSON, et on doit utiliser responseString2 au lieu de responseString à la ligne ci-dessous
    NSArray *tableau = [responseString JSONValue];
    [responseString release];
    NSDictionary *dico = [tableau objectAtIndex:0];//NSDictionary *dico = [responseString JSONValue]; // sans [], on aurait fais ceci!

    // Si cette condition est vérifiée, c'est que le token est recu. On vas alors relancer une requete pour avoir les données.
    if ([dico objectForKey:@"token"]) {
        [ [MySingleton sharedMySingleton] setAuth:[dico objectForKey:@"token"] ];

        //affichage du message de confirmation de sauvegarde des mots de passe
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login et Mot de passe" message:@"Votre login et votre mot de passe sont enregistrés." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert autorelease];
    }
}
```

Thanks for your reading / help !!!

Comment: @Leena : If I click on the first Tab, He will refresh the content of the UILabels with the NSUSerdefaults??? I don't think so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an observer :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(updateLabel:)
                                             name:@"LABELUPDATENOTIFICATION"
                                           object:nil];
```

in the class where the label exists i.e. 1st tab.

When the methods of the third button (launched trough those buttons) is invoked post a notification with updated text (NSString) object.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"LABELUPDATENOTIFICATION"
                                                    object:updatedStringLabelText]
```

Implement the following notification method in the class having the labels.

```
- (void)updateLabel:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSString *updatedText = (NSString*)[notification object];
    [yourLabel setText:updatedText];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help !!! I will try that today or tomorrow. THAAANKS! It's a great idea, those observer!

Comment: and I havee 2 labels to change in fact, how I identify the two post notifications? by its name??? of there is a simple way to différenciante those???

THANKS!

Comment: You have to add the observer in the class where the label needs to be updated. And implement the updateLabel in this same class itself.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to declare NSString in AppDelegate and u can change its value according to your button actions in third tab and assign the value in first tab label